# Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

Tags: python, npm, reserved-words

while running npm install (e.g. https://github.com/donpark/html2jade), I run into this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py:852: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp", line 15, in <module>
    import gyp
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gyp.input
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 852
    except ImportError as e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

python --version generates 'Python 2.7.1'

Answer (score 0):

This would not be a syntax error in Python 2.7.1. A quick workaround would be to run this programme as `python /full/path/to/scriptname.py`, which will actually use Python 2.7.1.

Comment: thanks for the feedback but this code is embedded into a package.json file which load files from internet. any clue how to push the usage of python 2.7.1 ?